# Cleanest and easiest way to have a rounded rectangle show up behind a navigation link on hover?

Tags: html, css, image, background, hover

Best way to understand what I want is to watch this short six second video.  Please ignore the font change in the video.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KM78DKoVZU

What's the best way to go about making that rounded rectangle to show up behind the navigation link on hover?  On hover, I could have the navigation button's background change to a background image with a rounded rectangle in the image, but before I go about that, I want to ensure there's no cleaner or easier way to go about this.

Thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The rectangle isn't really showing up behind the nav link. What's really happening is the nav link's style is changing during the hover state.

```
#menu { 
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 4px;
    color: #222;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
#menu li:hover { 
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius:6px;
}
```

Check out the jsFiddle for a live example.

http://jsfiddle.net/kGa67/

EDIT- I suppose the cleanest way is style both the ul and li as inline-block instead of floating the the li like I did. Use ems if you have a responsive design but beware that it doesn't always scale perfectly on very small and very large widths.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8PqkH/

It's easy to do.

```
nav a:hover{
    background: #902;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: .5em;
}
```